# Modifying which.max function in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have two rasters with data as below:

```
library("raster")
mdata <- raster(matrix(c(0,2,3, 11,12,13), nrow = 2, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE))
ndata <- raster(matrix(c(0,1,2, 11,14,13), nrow = 2, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE))
```

I want to stack them and estimate the maximum position with the criteria that if both the raster has value of 0, I should be able to write 0. This means that the output raster/matrix should have either 0, 1 or 2 in this case.

I tried following codes but it does not perform quite exactly the way I want.

```
odata <- stack(mdata, ndata)
e <- which.max(odata)
```

How should I be able to introduce the criteria that checks if both matrices have value of 0 for same position and assign 0 if there is?

I really appreciate your feedback on this.  Thanks!

Comment: PLease define "maximum position" , and provide a sample of what the output matrix (of zeros, ones and twos) is for your input sample. Otherwise,  simply setting `summat<-sum(mdata,ndata)` and checking for values which are zero there will suffice.

Comment: with the given matrices mdata and ndata above, which.max(odata) would give me a matrix(c(1,1,1,1,2,1)). 2 in this case indicates that the second raster (i.e., ndata) has higher value for [2,2] position. If the both matrices have same value, it assign the output matrix with 1 , i.e., the position of the first matrix. I want to have result with the matrix value c(0,1,1,1,2,1). THis is basically similar to the result I have been getting through which.max function except that I want to assign the cell that has 0 for both matrix with 0 not with 1.

Comment: I am trying to determine on a cell by cell basis the position of the raster with the maximum value in a set of rasters.  You solution seems to work if I have only two rasters.  However, I have 27 rasters to compare with, and create a raster with the position of the raster with the maximum value among 27 rasters.  So, I was trying to stack the layers of rasters, and used which.max function which partially meet my objective. I am just not being able to figure out how to accommodate the condition where I need to assign 0 if all the raster has 0 for the same position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
Rgames> foo<-matrix(rep(1,6),nr=2,nc=3)
Rgames> foo
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    1
Rgames> foo[(ndata-mdata >0)] <-2
Rgames> foo[(mdata==0 & ndata==0)] <-0

Rgames> foo
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    1    1
[2,]    1    2    1
```

I still can't tell from your question whether you want to locate the maximum of `mdata` or all locations where `mdata>ndata` , but if you clarify that it's easy to modify the conditionals to match.

EDIT: discuss extending to `N` layers of a raster.
To find which layer has the max at each location, I might use an `array`.

```
cube <- array(c(data.1,data.2,...),dim=c(dim(data.1),N)) #for N layers

# and I apologize but I may have loaded this 3-D cube in the wrong order
maxvals<-array(dim=dim(data.1))
for (j in 1:dim(data.1)[1]) {
for (k in 1:dim(data.1)[2]) {
maxvals[j,k]<-which.max(cube[j,k,])
if(sum(cube[j,k,])==0 ) maxvals[j,k] <- 0
}
}
```

This can probably be done a lot more efficiently with `aggregate` or `plyr` tools but I hope this points the way.

Comment: Thanks Carl for the solution. Actually, I ended up creating an matrix with all zeros, and kept it first while stacking. Eg. odata <- stack(zeromatrix, mdata, ndata); and used e <- which.max(odata). The way this works is whenever all the raster has zero, it automatically assign it to 1 as it comes first, and so on. This way I have the matrix with position of the raster with higher values. Then I renamed matrix with values 1:3 to 0:2.It just worked perfectly. Thanks again for helping me with this.